# Display createview(model form) and listview in the same template - Django

Tags: django, listview, django-class-based-views

how to display a modelForm CreateView and A listView on the same page. 
essentially I want users to reserve a rental by entering their name etc.. and the top of the page, and at the bottom of the page display information about the vehicles (model,make, etc)

I am using Class Based Views.

```
class CustomerOrderCreate(CreateView):
    template_name = 'webapp/index.html'
    model = CustomerOrder
    form_class = CustomerOrderCreateForm  // This works 

    vehicleData = VehicleOrder.objects.all()  // This Does not
```

Answer (score 0):

You could keep using your CreateView and add the list in the context like this:

```
class CustomerOrderCreate(CreateView):
    template_name = 'webapp/index.html'
    model = CustomerOrder
    form_class = CustomerOrderCreateForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        return dict(
            super(CustomerOrderCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs),
            vehicle_orders=VehicleOrder.objects.all()[0:100]
        )
```

Then in your template, you can do:

```
{% for order in vehicle_orders %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

---

Alternatively, especially if you're going to add more custom logic, you could use a function for your view instead. Class based view are great but can become big/complicated really quickly.